# Pigeonhole Principle for "n people each in exactly p out of q committees" type of problem

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Question: Suppose there're 100 people in 15 committees of 20 people each, and that each person is on exactly 3 committees. Show that there exist 2 committees with overlap >= 3.

I know there's a solution using expected number of overlaps of any pair of committee. I want to know how to solve this problem (and problems of this type) in a purely combinatorial way (possibly using Pigeonhole Principle.)

Comment: If the overlap between any two committees is always $\le 2$, then list the committees in order. The first committee includes 20 new people. The second committee includes at least 18 new people, the third committee includes at least 16 new people, etc.

Comment: Did you set up the standard incidence matrix? If you could row pairs (100 rows of individuals), that should lead to the contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

We can think about it like this:

If we have $300$ people and $15$ committees, each will have $20$ with each person in only one committee.

If one person can serve in two committees, then we would need $\frac{300}{2} = 150$ people.

And so if one person can serve in three committees, we would need $\frac{300}{3} = 100$ people.

This makes sense as we would need all $\frac{300}{15} = 20$ people if each can serve in all $15$ committees.